# Unable to calculate mean using aggregate for table, result comes out as N/A

Tags: r

Currently using R to calculate the mean and standard deviation for each combination of Sex and Genotype in a given table:

```
id Sex     Genotype  Activity
  1 male    ff        1.884 
  2 male    ff        2.283 
  3 male    fs        2.396 
  4 female  ff        2.838   
  5 male    fs        2.956 
  6 female  ff        4.216 
  7 female  ss        3.620
```

I made a table called tabled using the function

```
tabled <- table(data$Sex, data$Genotype)
```

When I try calculating the mean I try the following function:

```
aggregate(data$Sex ~ data$Genotype, by=list(data$Genotype), FUN=mean)
```

The output I get is

```
Group.1 data$Sex
<fctr> <dbl>
ff     NA           
fs     NA           
ss     NA           
3 rows
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: `aggregate(Activity ~., data[-1],  FUN=mean)`

Comment: You conflate two styles of `aggregate`. The formula version includes the *by* grouping. Choose one and not the other.

Comment: What is the mean of 4 males and 3 females?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the formula method.  Here, we subset the columns of interest by removing the first column (`data[-1]`), specify the column to be summarised on the lhs of `~` ('Activity`) and complete the formula with`.` (which signifies for all the other columns)

```
aggregate(Activity ~., data[-1], FUN=mean)
#    Sex Genotype Activity
#1 female       ff   3.5270
#2   male       ff   2.0835
#3   male       fs   2.6760
#4 female       ss   3.6200
```

---

In the OP's code, it is mixing up the formula method with `data.frame` method.

Comment: I was considering removing the first ID role, I appreciate it, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. What exactly does Activity ~. do in this case? Can you explain it?

Comment: @Janus when we have n columns, and if one of the column is used for taking the mean, then the remaining are n-1, those n-1 columns are the grouping variables signified by `.`

Comment: alternatively and more explicitly: 

aggregate(Activity ~ Sex + Genotype, data=data, FUN=mean)

Answer (score 1):

You're using formula notation as well as a `by` parameter. I think this is redundant.

You're also not telling aggregate what you want to take the mean of, which is the reason for the error (mean is only applicable to numerical values).

For the formula-style, use akrun's answer. Here's a solution with "by" parameter.

`with(data, aggregate(list("Activity"=Activity), by=list("Genotype"=Genotype, "Sex"=Sex), FUN=mean))`

Comment: Be sure to also send named lists for better column headers than *Group.#* and *x*: `with(data, aggregate(list(Activity=Activity), by=list(Genotype=Genotype, Sex=Sex), FUN=mean))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using `data.table` package -

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(dt)[,mean:=mean(Activity),by=.(Sex,Genotype)]

> dt
   id    Sex Genotype Activity   mean
1:  1   male       ff    1.884 2.0835
2:  2   male       ff    2.283 2.0835
3:  3   male       fs    2.396 2.6760
4:  4 female       ff    2.838 3.5270
5:  5   male       fs    2.956 2.6760
6:  6 female       ff    4.216 3.5270
7:  7 female       ss    3.620 3.6200
```

**OR**

```
> setDT(dt)[,mean(Activity),by=.(Sex,Genotype)]

      Sex    Genotype     V1
1:   male       ff     2.0835
2:   male       fs     2.6760
3: female       ff     3.5270
4: female       ss     3.6200
```